Cone avoidance and $\Pi^0_1$-classes
Suppose $X \subseteq 2^{\omega}$ is nonempty and $\Pi^0_1$ relative to $a$. Assume $c_0 \nleq_T b_0 \oplus a$ and $c_1 \nleq_T b_1 \oplus a$.  Must there exist some $y \in X$ such that $c_i \nleq_T b_i \oplus y$ for $i = 0, 1$? All I know is that this is true if $b_0 = b_1$.

The answer is yes. It boils down to two cases:

${X}$ has computable members relative to ${a}$. Let's say ${f\in X}$ is such a member, then clearly it won't add computational content to help compute either of the ${c_i}$'s so the relations hold.
By a result of Jockush and Soare relativized to ${a}$, if ${X}$ contains no computable member relative to ${a}$, then it contains $2^{\omega}$ incomparable degrees not comparable with any countable set of turing degrees which gives us what we want.

